# What makes message not delivered to device when using Google FCM v1 API?

Tags: java, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building a push notification service by using Firebase Cloud Messaging v1. We are using 2 ways, through tokens and topics. But in both way, wa have a problem, the response from server returned 200, OK, however, some of our devices received the message and some didn't (even it got the 200 response code from server). Normally, 100% of our devices get the notifications but the missing issues above sometime happens and I do not know what is the reason. So what made the message come late or what did I do wrong?

Thank you!

p/s: My system is using java.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that some of the devices you are sending to are offline at the time of the sending.

Note that the 200 response from FCM is confirmation that the send request was successfully received by FCM. FCM will attempt to send to all devices targeted however if the one or more of the targeted devices are not connected then FCM will not be able to send the message.

If you are sure that the devices are online and still not receiving the messages then I would file a ticket with [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/).

Comment: Yeah, I got your point, but all of my devices are connected to the Internet, so I don't think we can say that is offline issues, My tokens list is so small, just 5 or 6.

Comment: Cool in that case you should file a support ticket with more details eg: each of the 5 device tokens and when you sent the message how many were received/not received, your sender ID and other relevant information. They should be able to track down the issue.